# "Incomplete escape" error while using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Recently I ran into a problem with “conda”. When I try to install a package with “conda install” or when I try simply to run “conda list” in Spyder or Qt Console I get an error: “incomplete escape \U”, however I do not add any "" to the command. This error started appearing a couple of weeks ago, even though I didn’t update anything.
Python version of the environment I am working at: 3.10.13.
How can I fix that?

I already tried creating new environment and reinstalled Anaconda Navigator, but the error still occures.That is the whole error description I am getting when trying to run "conda list" in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[1], line 1
get_ipython().run_line_magic(‘conda’, ‘list’)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2456 in run_line_magic
result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:30 in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:128 in conda
conda = _get_conda_like_executable(“conda”)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:53 in _get_conda_like_executable
match = re.search(

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\re.py:200 in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\re.py:303 in _compile
p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_compile.py:788 in compile
p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:955 in parse
p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:444 in _parse_sub
itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:841 in _parse
p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:444 in _parse_sub
itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:526 in _parse
code = _escape(source, this, state)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Thesis\lib\sre_parse.py:382 in _escape
raise source.error(“incomplete escape %s” % escape, len(escape))

error: incomplete escape \U`
```